# how to cover custom exception class with tests?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have the following custom exception class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception{
    public CustomException(List <SObject> contextRecordList,dmlException ex)
    {
        String s = ex.getMessage() + ' ' + ex.getStacktraceString();
        contextRecordList.get(0).addError(s,false);
    } 

    public CustomException(List <SObject> contextRecordList,List <sObject> recordsToProcess,dmlException ex)
    {
        String className = fetchRegexData(ex.getStacktraceString(),'(?:.*?\\.){1}(.*?)(?=\\:)'); //2 for only func
        String dmlType = ex.getMessage().split(' ')[0];
        String errorMessage = fetchRegexData(ex.getMessage(),'(?<=.EXCEPTION, )(.*)');
        String customStackTraceInfo = className + ': line ' + ex.getLineNumber();
        String triggerType = getTriggerType(ex.getStacktraceString());
        String processedRecordType = '' + recordsToProcess.get(0).getSObjectType();

        String s = 'ERROR: On "' + processedRecordType + '" ' + dmlType + ': "' +  errorMessage + '". (DEVELOPER INFO: ' + customStackTraceInfo + ', IN TRIGGER: ' + triggerType + ')';

        contextRecordList.get(0).addError(s,false); 
    }
}
```

In this case the `contextRecordList` variable corresponds to `Trigger.new`.

How do I write tests for this class? How do I call these constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the behavior of this class, it's mostly about string parsing, so that makes it difficult to do much. However, in terms of calling the constructors, you can just instantiate an exception as input, without any need to throw it.

So from a code coverage perspective, all you really need is:

```
static testmethod void testMyException()
{
    final String originalMessage = 'Hello World!';
    List<SObject> records = new List<SObject> { /*some records*/ };
    DmlException d = new DmlException();
    d.setMessage(originalMessage();

    Test.startTest();
        MyCustomException e = new MyCustomException(records, d);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

However, unit tests are not about code coverage, but rather verifying application behavior, which you do with rigorous use of assertions. The only way to assert that `addError` was called is to run through the trigger context where it gets invoked. So your only way to truly test this exception is through trigger tests.

I would just like to note that your approach seems to complicate things more than is necessary. You don't need to use an exception class to validate using apex. You just call `addError` and be done with it. The advantage of using just `addError` and not throwing an exception is that partial operations can then allow some records to go through.

You also *only* add the error to the first record, which will lead to some inconsistent behavior, depending on how you use this class. You should treat each record in your trigger collection the same.

Comment: can you explain why is it complicating things? what the alternative? i didn't really understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test Sobject.addError(String) method.

```
Test.startTest();
     //your code where CustomException is thrown 
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals(1, ApexPages.getMessages().size(), 'There should have been 1 Page Message');
System.assertEquals('Expected error message added by means of addError method', ApexPages.getMessages().get(0).getSummary() , 'The message summary doesn\'t match');
```

Comment: but how can i call this function with "Trigger.New"? this doesn't really answer the question..

Comment: Trigger.New  is trigger context variable (all records that are inserted in transaction are present in Trigger.New list). It is related to newly created records.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an entry point from were you can `throw` an exception from your trigger. Add something like this in your trigger code and try to cover trigger with appropriate data and you will be done.

```
try {
    if(condition1) {
        throw new CustomException (contextRecordList,recordsToProcess,ex);

    } else if(condition2){
        throw new CustomException (contextRecordList,ex);
    }
} catch(CustomException ex) {
    System.debug('Exception:'+ex);
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear? i didn't really understand

Comment: Same thing which Derek highlighted in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would write a test purely for your exception class that constructed it and asserted its behaviour.

But as it is not possible in a test to create a fully setup `DmlException` instance, you are instead forced to test it by invoking the code that it is used from. Search in your code base for where it is used and call that code in such a way that this exception is generated and then assert the results.

**PS**

Correction, you can setup the fields of a `DmlException` that your code handles as in fact it only references the "Common Exception Methods" (see the [Exception Class and Built-In Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) documentation). So in your test you could do:

```
List <SObject> contextRecords = ...;
List <SObject> recordsToProcess = ...;
DmlException e = new DmlException('hello world');

CustomException ce = new CustomException(contextRecords, recordsToProcess, e);
try {
    // Need to do DML to get the error turned into an exception
    upsert contextRecords;
} catch (DmlException ex) {
    System.asertEquals('expected text', ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Its quite complex to reproduce the scenario by code, isn't any other way?

Comment: @D.Griff If your objective is to really test the code including the internal methods like `getTriggerType` then you may have to. One of the points of writing the tests as you write the code is to separate the code out so that it can be tested as part of the code development. If that is not done you can end up in this situation where it is very hard to test the separate pieces. But see my PS.

Comment: Actually stack trace is set at construction time, not when thrown.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks, didn't realise that - I'll simplify the code.

Comment: The reason its complex because this error occures only when one sobject tries to update another. for example: i try to add a primary contact to an account, but the account doesnt pass the validation rules, so when i try to save the contact, i get an error on the account. its complex because i can't really reproduce this scenario by code